# I cannot load my dataset on a python installed on EC2 windows instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, numpy, amazon-ec2

I am trying these lines in python 3.5 installed on aws EC2 windows instance:

```
import numpy as np
mydata=np.loadtxt('c:\full_path\mydataset.txt', delimiter=None)
```

And I receive the error:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ...

I tried several tricks including using os.path, using other packages such as pandas for reading the file. In fact I cannot load any file. I always get the same error. I should say the code works perfectly fine on my own laptop.

Answer (score 1):

Escape the backslash.

```
mydata=np.loadtxt('c:\\full_path\\mydataset.txt', delimiter=None)
```

Comment: Then the file doesn't exist.

Comment: The file is there, I actually tried in different locations with different paths also different files, always the same error. Btw, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to make another instance to see if the problem will insist. The problematic ec2 instance was windows server 2012 R2, and the new one is windows server 2012.  Fortunately, all codes are working perfectly fine on the new instance!